# React Native app crashes when calling .getToken() on @react-native-firebase/messaging

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase, react-native-cli

I am a developing a bare react native app with **react native cli**.

I recentlty integrated firebase and installed **@react-native-firebase/messaging.**

When calling **.getToken() of messaging**

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
await messaging().getToken() <------------ CAUSING APP TO CLOSE
```

Everytime I add this line the app closes without any warnings and logs, It dosen't happen when I comment the line

**Here's my AndroidManifest.XML**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.NAME.NAME">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-9772207663610474XXXXXXXXXX"/>
  <meta-data 
        android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
        android:value="false"/>
    <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
  <meta-data  
        android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->
                <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**Here's the Android/build.gradle**

```
   buildscript {
   ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"  
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
    firebaseVersion = "+"
    firebaseMessagingVersion = "+"
}
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
    dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}
    allprojects {
    repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
    }
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
    }

    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
}}
```

Comment: Happening in emulator ?

Comment: It's happening in android device, via usb debugging.

Comment: Tried permission thing that i have given in answer ?

Comment: @Pulkitsaini how did you fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this line to your Android/app/build.gradle?

```
implementation platform(‘com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1’)
```

If you did, try to remove it, clean, rebuild and run the project again.

Answer (score 1):

```
firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
```

resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to `"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0"` in `package.json` and changing `firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"` in the `buildscript.ext` of `android/build.gradle` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check messaging permission before the executing this line.

```
_checkPermission = async() => {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
        const device = await firebase.messaging().getToken()
        console.warn(device)
    }
    else this._getPermission() 
} 

_getPermission = async() => {
    firebase.messaging().requestPermission()
    .then(() => {
        this._checkPermission()
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // User has rejected permissions  
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried it earlier, Now tried it again, but still the same case.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE” /> is this in your android ?

Comment: Just added it to my AndroidManifest.XML, rerun -> npx react-native run-android, But still the same issue